# Error null: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, html, spring, primefaces

Buen día Tengo problemas para leer un archivo Excel que esta en memoria el cual me arroja el siguiente error desde mi consola del servidor:

```
09:58:08,179 SEVERE [mx.com.mi.proyect.view.MiBean] (default task-10) null: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\jboss-eap-7.3\standalone\tmp\SRVMiProyecto.war\undertow5329760000588363508upload
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData$FileItem.getInputStream(FormData.java:240)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl.getInputStream(PartImpl.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.model.NativeUploadedFile.getInputstream(NativeUploadedFile.java:81)
    at mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean.ejecutarInsertarExcel(MiBean.java:477)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:245)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:338)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:198)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:280)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:65)
```

Y desde mis logs me arroja esto:

```
09:57:46.483 [default task-10] DEBUG mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[188]  - Valor de ejercicioActual : 2022
09:57:57.423 [default task-9] DEBUG mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[455]  - Entra org.primefaces.model.NativeUploadedFile@5244bb86
09:57:57.423 [default task-9] DEBUG mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[460]  - Carga de Archivo ...
09:57:57.424 [default task-9] DEBUG mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[461]  - FileName Excel... 11111.xlsx 
09:57:57.424 [default task-9] DEBUG mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[462]  - event.getFile() ... 8635 
09:58:08.178 [default task-10] DEBUG mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[472]  - Valida Archivo Excel...org.primefaces.model.NativeUploadedFile@5244bb86
09:58:08.178 [default task-10] DEBUG mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[475]  - validaArchivos TRUE
09:58:08.189 [default task-10] ERROR mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[481]  - Ocurrio un error en EXCEL C:\jboss-eap-7.3\standalone\tmp\SRVMiProyecto.war\undertow5329760000588363508upload 
09:58:08.189 [default task-10] ERROR mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[482]  - Ocurrio un error en EXCEL C:\jboss-eap-7.3\standalone\tmp\SRVMiProyecto.war\undertow5329760000588363508upload 
09:58:08.189 [default task-10] ERROR mx.com.mi.proyecto.view.MiBean[483]  - Ocurrio un error en EXCEL java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\jboss-eap-7.3\standalone\tmp\SRVMiProyecto.war\undertow5329760000588363508upload
```

Lo que yo entiendo es que no esta leyendo el archivo por que encuentra la ruta para leerlo
pero para leerlo lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
public void ejecutarInsertarExcel() throws BaseJdbcException {
    FileInputStream inputstream;

    LOG.debug("Valida Archivo Excel...{}",uploadedFileExcel);
    
    if (uploadedFileExcel != null) {
        LOG.debug("validaArchivos TRUE");
        try {
            inputstream = (FileInputStream) uploadedFileExcel.getInputstream();
            LOG.debug("inputstream ...{}",uploadedFileExcel);
            LeerElExcel(inputstream);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MiBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            LOG.error("Ocurrio un error en EXCEL {} ", ex.getMessage());
            LOG.error("Ocurrio un error en EXCEL {} ", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            LOG.error("Ocurrio un error en EXCEL {} ", ex.toString());
        }
        
    } else {
        LOG.debug("validaArchivos FALSE");
    }
    
}
```

Y la parte donde se sube el Excel es esta:

```
<tr align="center">
    <th align="left" valign="middle" scope="row">
        <h:outputLabel value="Pasar DATOS" />
        <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjaxPasarDatos" ajax="true" value="#{miBean.barraProgreso}" labelTemplate="{value}%"
            global="false" interval="500">
            <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{miBean.onComplete}" oncomplete="PF('PasarDatos').enable()" />
        </p:progressBar>
    </th>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <p:outputPanel id="panelUploadExcel">
            <p:fileUpload id="pbUploadExcel" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{miBean.cargarArchivoExcel}"
                invalidFileMessage="Archivo con formato inválido" requiredMessage="Archivo con formato inválido"
                mode="advanced" skinSimple="true" process="@this" label="Debe seleccionar su archivo" fileLimit="1"
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xlsx)$/" update="panelUploadExcel" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Archivo cargado : #{miBean.fileNameExcel}"
                rendered="#{not empty miBean.fileNameExcel}" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </td>

    <td align="center">
        <p:commandButton value="#{i18n['web.iniciar']}" widgetVar="PasarDatos">
            <pp:exporter type="xlsx" target="" fileName="#{miBean.fileNameExcel}"
                postProcessor="#{miBean.ejecutaInsertarDatos()}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Como les comento la verdad que no encuentro el por que del error pues se supone que el archivo lo jala desde la memoria para poder leerlo, sin embargo no encuentro la raíz del error. Espero me puedan ayudar u orientar

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: por favor aclara, el archivo excel esta en memoria o es un archivo temporal?

Comment: tengo entendido que el archivo esta en Memoria. o bueno así es como entiendo que así es como funciona el comando **uploadedFileExcel **